# Implementing a smarter $.extend?

Tags: jquery

we like to declare a collection of settings to use in a plugin:

```
var settings = { x: 0, y: 1 };
```

and then extend/override them with user options upon a call:

```
function x(opts) {
    opts = $.extend(settings, opts);
...
x({ y: 2 });
```

...which all works great except when you nest options:

```
var settings = { x: 0, y: 1, files: { path: '/', names: { xml: 'x', kml: 'k' } } }

x({ files: { path: '/tmp' } });
```

which wipes out the contents of `files` such that the names are gone.

my interest is to only specify the file path but `$.extend` isn't smart enough to accomplish that. or is it? how is this typically handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already been implemented using the deep parameter of [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN):

```
jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )
```

For example:

```js
var settings = {
  x: 0,
  y: 1,
  files: {
    path: '/',
    names: {
      xml: 'x',
      kml: 'k'
    }
  }
};

function x(opts) {
  opts = $.extend(true, settings, opts);
  console.dir(opts);
}

x({
  files: {
    path: '/tmp'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- open your browser's console to see the output -->
```